# C alternative to fputs()/fgets() with open()

Tags: c, kernel-module, fgets, fcntl

I'm learning about kernel modules communicating with user level programs and originally was opening a file with

```
FILE *pFile = fopen(...)
```

and writing to it with

```
char *str = malloc(10);
fputs(str, pFile);
```

However now I need to use functionality in `#include <fcntl.h>` to attempt some asynchronous notifications and the example I have instead uses

```
int pFile;
pFile = open("/dev/mymodule", O_RDWR);
```

I think that I can no longer use `fputs()` or `fgets()` because it requires a `FILE *ptr` and I have an `int` instead now. I think I'm supposed to use `write()` and `read()` instead.

Is this how it would work?

```
write(pFile, str,  sizeof(str));

char line[256];
    while (read(pFile, line, 256) != NULL) {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
```

Comment: `read` doesn't return `NULL`. Check its documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open a `FILE*` based on the file descriptor with `fdopen()`:

```
FILE *file = fdopen(pfile, "rw");
```

Reference: [fdopen - associate a stream with a file descriptor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fdopen.html)

Comment: does this allow me to use fputs/fgets and things like: `fcntl(pFile, F_SETOWN, getpid());  filp->f_owner
 oflags = fcntl(pFile, F_GETFL);
 fcntl(pFile, F_SETFL, oflags | FASYNC);`  ?

Comment: You can use `fgets()` and `fputs()` on the `FILE*` and `fcntl()` on the `int`. Just don't mix reading and writing the `FILE*` with reading and writing the `int`, as the `FILE*` is buffered and the `int` isn't, so things will get out of sync.